# Changing the style of a specific block

Tags: blocks

I need to change the color of a specific block in Drupal. But no matter what I try in CSS it does not work, I know the code is correct as I have tried it in a different scenario (in Codepen) and it works fine so it must be a Drupal setting of some sort?

I want to change the background color of the second "testimonial" block.

```
<div class="testimonials">
  <div class="testimonials-content">
    <div class="cover-component-slide">

    </div>
  </div>
```

This works but not when I add it to my theme global css:

```
div.testimonials:last-of-type .cover-component-slide{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Whatever I try with pseudo-classes either doesn't change anything or the background color of both blocks.

Comment: Drupal can’t affect how css works in the browser - your styles are either not being loaded at all, or the rule isn’t specific enough when you look at it in the context of the rest of the CSS loaded on the page

Comment: Try to use `!important` maybe the property background of this block has been already used somewhere use `!important` to force using your background color.

Comment: well try Block Class module

Comment: Use your browser Development tools to select the `.cover-component-slide` element and see if it has your CSS applied anywhere (it may be overridden by other rules of more specificity). Use some obvious simple selector and put in your theme, clear CSS cache and see if it appears. If not, there is a bug in your theme that isn't including the file you're editing (can you see the file in the head?). Check your HTML that the `div.testimonials` really is the last of type, or don't use the pseudo-class to test. You can use `!important` to test specificity. What "both blocks" are you talking about?